# How to bypass SSL verification for Gradle 4.5?

Tags: java, ssl, gradle

I am getting this error while trying to connect to Nexus Maven proxy repository, but Nexus is running over HTTPS with a self-signed certificate.

How can I bypass SSL verification in this scenario in Gradle 4.5?

```
sun.security.validator.validatorexception pkix path building failed 
sun.security.provider.certpath.suncertpathbuilderexception: 
  unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: @MartinZeitler That is not a good duplicate of this question. This question asks how to configure Gradle to not issue the error. The question you suggested as duplicate is about solving that with a 'normal' Java application.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it's likely a Java problem, not exactly a Gradle problem... and one can pass any of the stated settings in `gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, *we did not have access to import certificates in cacerts*. But, we were able to install the certificates in Windows `Trusted Root Certification Authority`. In `gradle.properties`, after adding below 2 properties, I was able to override cacerts and get over the SSL issue

```
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\\Windows\\win.ini
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT
```

Answer (score 0):

it works for me with below gradle.properties

```
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=$JAVA_HOME//jre//lib//security//cacerts
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

Comment: This won't fix your issue if Nexus is using a self-signed certificate and you have not added that certificate to `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` (Java's trust store).

Comment: cannot imagine it to be working without `keytool` and `importcert`. see [discuss.gradle.org](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/disable-ssl-cert-validation/24092/12).

Comment: When I do this, I get `RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty`, from one of my gralde plugins (the one that was failing due to SSL to being with)